# Flutter how to change image after onTap with Gesture Detector

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I have a Image inside a GestureDetector widget. I want to change this image when **onTapDown** is called, and then change it again when **onTapUp** is called. Is there possible to do that? 
In other app (Native Android app with java), I used to do it using a button and changing its background with a selector xml, like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image2"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
```

so, is there a way to do the same in flutter?

---JUST TO BE CLEAR---

In the same widget, I want an image if it is not pressed and a different image if it is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image img;
// example: Image.asset('images/camera.png',)
Image imgUp =  Image.asset('your image directory for when tap up',);
Image imgDown =  Image.asset('your image directory for when tapdown',);

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 img = imgUp;
 }


GestureDetector(
      //your image is here
      child: img,
      onTapDown: (tap){
        setState(() {
          // when it is pressed
          img =  imgDown;
        });
      },
      onTapUp: (tap){
        setState(() {
          // when it is released
          img = imgUp;
        });
      },
```

[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEwYB.png)  You can change the image when it is pressed and released using gesture detector
It is super easy you don't need any extra library or package you have to just use 
setState() in order to update the view when you pressed an released

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this myself, so give it a try and see if it suits your need.

For such application, you could give `provider` a try.

For example,

```
final provider = Provider.of<myProvider>(context);

...
Image(
   image: AssetImage(provider.imageFile),
),     
...
GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: () => provider.imageForTapDown(),
  onTapUp: () => provider.imageForTapUp()
);
```

then in `provider`,

```
void imageForTapDown(){
 //Change the image file
 imageFile = changeImageforTapDown;

 notifyListeners();
)

void imageForTapUp(){
 //Change the image file
 imageFile = changeImageforTapUp;

 notifyListeners();
)
```

You can read more about the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Make sure you apply optimization as `notifyListeners` will rebuild whenever `listen: true` in the provider (you can target specific image using `selector` of provider).

Hope this helps.