# Flutter how to change SVG after onTap with Gesture Detector

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, gesturedetector

Wanna implement same functionality that is done here with images:

[Flutter how to change image after onTap with Gesture Detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792716/flutter-how-to-change-image-after-ontap-with-gesture-detector)

Im using this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg/example

Even though I'm able to do this in IconButton, I need this in GestureDetector, not in IconButton, so just to be clear, need help how to implement SVG into GestureDetector not IconButton!

I'm able to get SVG rendered on the screen but can't figure it out how to implement it in GestureDetector, to render SVG on screen, Im doing it like this:

```
Expanded svgTest({double blackKeyWidth}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/1.svg',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
              width: 500,
            ),
            onPressed: null //do something,
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Cant figure out how to implement SVG in GestureDetector, it can't go in as Image and Gesture Detector doesn't accept icon, or Im not doing it right.

Thank

Comment: do you want to change it one time or everytime on a tap ?

Comment: Every time, I want to implement SVG into GestureDetector not into IconButton, I posted IconButton code here just as an example of what I was able to do on my own, though I want SVG to change every time onTapDown and onTapUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the image on the `onTap` method of the `iconButton` then you should have to change the *path* of the `image` in `onTap` method using `setState`

```
String imagePath = "assets/images/1.svg";

Expanded svgTest({double blackKeyWidth}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: IconButton(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              '${imagePath}',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
              width: 500,
            ),
            onPressed: (){
               setState(() {
                  imagePath = "assets/images/2.svg";
                });
},
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**EDITED:** (For Gesture Detector You Can Simply Wrap the SVG in it)

*Replace* *the* `iconbutton` *with* *the* `GestureDetector` and Add its `onTap` and `onTapUp` methods too.

```
  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        imagePath = "assets/images/2.svg";
      });
    },
    onTapUp: (TapUpDetails tapUpDetails) {
      setState(() {
        imagePath = "assets/images/1.svg";
      });
    },
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
      '${imagePath}',
      //fit: BoxFit.fill,
      //allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
      //width: 500,
    ),
  ),
```

[For More About GestureDetector and Flutter SVG Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219283/9577961)

Comment: Want to implement SVG in GestureDetector, need extra functionalities that it offers, like that SVG changes again onTapUp

Comment: @Jan Please Check the updated Code, and also tell what problem are you facing with the GestureDetector